VB6 GET method to read binary into a 3 dimensional byte array
I'm working with some legacy VB6 code that reads a binary file and loads the data into a 3 dimensional byte array using the following code:
Public RawData(200, 200, 1000) As Byte '(x,y,value)
Open Name For Binary Access Read As #OpenFileNumber                
Seek #OpenFileNumber, i 'go to the position where the data starts
Get #OpenFileNumber, , RawData 'this reads the data into the correct location in the 3 dimensional (200,200,1000) byte array


The data in the binary file comprises of  40,000 locations (x=200, y=200) in each of which there are 1000 readings. The byte data in the file is a continuous and there seems to be no separator character so I think the data is located in the array purely on its position in the byte data.
The code works fine in VB6 but I cant find anything in the documentation for the GET method that explains how binary data is read into a 3D array and I dont know the structure of the binary data in the file.
For a 1D array I guess it would just load each byte sequentially but how does this work for a 3D array? If I could understand that I could then work out the structure of the data. I'm coding some routines to analyse this data in vb.net.
I guessed the first 1000 bytes was for location (1,1), the next 1000 for (1,2), etc but that isn't the case  so I think the data must be organised to suit the VB6 GET method using a 3D array.

VB is column-major for its internal array format, so I would expect the first 1000 bytes to be for (*,1,1), the next 1000 to be for (*,2,1), and so on.  I'm not sure whether there are any additional markers to be expected for file structure.

Thanks, Ill give that a go. Examining the data I think there seems to be a sudden change in the values after the first 200 bytes, so maybe that's a clue.

See this explanation taken from the below linked SO question "Reading VB6 three-dimensional array in FreePascal/Lazarus which explains how VB6 handles data type storage. You need to scroll down a fair bit for the Array part.

I would recommend writing a VB6 test program that dumps some known data values into a file yourself. Then you can inspect the bytes of that file and see what the pattern was
